# SQL- How to get the most repeated text value per group during an aggregate operation?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

Here I explain. I have these 2 tables:

STUDENTS

```
Student_ID  HighSchool

ST_001      East High
ST_002      East High
ST_003      East High
ST_004      East High
ST_005      San Marino
ST_006      San Marino
ST_007      Tall Oaks
ST_008      Tall Oaks
```

MEDICAL_TESTS

```
TestKit_ID  Student_ID   Class    Urine_results  Body_type

MedTest001  ST_001      English      0.8            I
MedTest002  ST_001      English      0.6            II
MedTest003  ST_003      English      0.8            II
MedTest004  ST_005      Math         0.6            IV
MedTest005  ST_005      Math         1.0            IV
MedTest006  ST_005      Math         1.4            III
MedTest007  ST_006      English      0.5            II
MedTest008  ST_006      English      0.6            III
```

I need a summary table that specifies all the classes, two summary columns of the medical/body results (AVG_urineRes and MOST_FREQ_BodyType) of the students in each class, and the school such classes are offered at.
See example query result table below:

```
HighSchool  Class     AVG_UrineRes  Body_type (most frequent per class)

East High   English       0.6           II
San Marino  Math          1.0           IV
San Marino  English       0.55          III
```

But, **how to get the most frequent body_type aggregate column?** My script at this point looks like:

```
Select s.highShool, m.class, AVG(m.urine_results), MOST_FREQ(m.body_type)
FROM Student s INNER JOIN MedicalTest m ON (s.Student_ID = m.Student_ID)
GROUP BY s.highShool, m.class
```

If there was a MOST_FREQ function like in my snippet above, it would be great! but there is not. Any suggestion/solution would be appreciated. And sorry the tables structure might look a little weird. I tried to adapt a real problem into this example.

Comment: Follow the [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) for similar answers. Non-HTML tables would of been easier to read too.

Comment: What makes you decide for type III for San Marino / English? Type II occurs just as often. Does some rule apply here or are you picking a value arbitrarily?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Thorsten. Yes, arbitrarily. I'm actually using access, but I just downloaded MYSQL last week, so a solution in the latest version of MySQL will also work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like following query.

```
 SELECT S.highschool, 
           MT.class, 
           Avg(urine_result), 
           (SELECT body_type 
            FROM   medical_tests M 
                   INNER JOIN students S1 
                           ON M.student_id = S1.student_id 
            WHERE  M.class = MT.class 
                   AND S1.highschool = S.highschool 
            GROUP  BY M.body_type 
            ORDER  BY Count(*)   desc
              LIMIT 1)MOST_FREQ 
    FROM   students S 
           INNER JOIN medical_tests MT 
                   ON MT.student_id = S.student_id 
    GROUP  BY S.highschool, 
              MT.class;
```